# SAP Java Connector (JCo) mocking server

Tags: testing, mocking, jco

Is there are any mock servers that I can connect with a JCo client library and test my client code. I'm developing a code for a SAP client and I do not have the access to the server at the moment, but I need to verify that the code works with a mock server. Anybody knows how to do this? thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no mock SAP servers available freely. The best way you can have this is register for a [SAP netweaver](http://www.sapdocs.info/1674/sap-netweaver-trial-downloads/) trial version and set it up in your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend mocking the SBO in all but the most trivial cases since the complexity of the integration comes mostly form the behavior of the server.

For trivial cases use a standard mocking framework like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a Java lib with SAP Jco library for the testing. Thanks anyway mokito is indeed a good one too.